# How do I access a variable that is inside a function outside the function in python?

Tags: python, variables, combobox

I have a combo box containing all of the countries and as the user picks a country, the country picked is stored in the variable country inside of a function. However, I will need to access the local variable (country) outside of the function. Can somebody help me find a way to access the local variable outside the function it is declared in.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

countries = ('afghanistan',
                        'albania',
                        'algeria',
                        'andorra',
                        'angola',
                        'anguilla',)

countries_cb = ttk.Combobox(root)
countries_cb['values'] = countries
countries_cb['state'] = 'readonly' 
countries_cb.pack(fill='y', padx=5, pady=5)

def countries_changed(event):
    msg = f'You selected {countries_cb.get()}!'
    showinfo(message=msg)
    country=(countries_cb.get()) #the local variable i want to access outside of the function
    print(country)

countries_cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', countries_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when the function finishes execution it along with it's variable gone, why don't you try with global bariables?

Comment: it prints:Temp
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\teera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: countries_changed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'country'          When I use a local variable

Comment: Why do you have a `country` parameter in `countries_changed`?

Comment: that was from i tried to use a global variable (country) and tried to pass it as a parameter but it didn't work. sorry i will remove it as it can cause confusion

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and have ran out of solutions. The ```global``` variable is not a sufficient approach for tkinter. If the user is to select one item from a dropdown list as many times as they want, we should be able to access what the user chooses every time, but using global outside the function in the main flow will only return the value the user chooses for the FIRST time, and then skips it to the next code lines. Somebody help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just read the value of local variable in outside of the function, return it from the function. Like this

```py
def countries_changed(event):
    msg = f'You selected {countries_cb.get()}!'
    showinfo(message=msg)
    country=(countries_cb.get()) #the local variable i want to access outside of the function
    print(country)

country_local = countries_changed(event, country)
```

Or if you want to modify it in outside the function, use `global` keyword.

```py
country = ''
def countries_changed(event):
    global country
    msg = f'You selected {countries_cb.get()}!'
    showinfo(message=msg)
    country=(countries_cb.get()) #the local variable i want to access outside of the function
    print(country)

print(country)
```

Comment: when I use the global variable it is coming up with the syntax error: name 'country' is parameter and global. How can I fix this

Comment: Check now. I edited the answer. (Removed country from function parameters)

Comment: It is now coming up with the error that event is not defined which is weird as I didn't define it in my earlier code and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable country is local, you can't access it from outside the function.
The keyword `global` helps with this issue.
Try:

```
  def countries_changed(event, country):
    global country
    msg = f'You selected {countries_cb.get()}!'
    showinfo(message=msg)
    country=(countries_cb.get()) #the local variable i want to access outside of the function
    print(country)
```

Comment: Its coming up with the syntax error: name 'country' is parameter and global